# How Can I Use Haskell Types to Overload Methods

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a little project where I am trying to learn Haskell and whip up a program to help plan student schedules. I have the following types:

```
data Course =
    { id :: Int, title :: String }
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Req = Single Course
    | Any [Req]
    | All [Req]
    deriving Show
```

Now I want to write a method:

```
satisfies :: [Course] -> Req -> Bool
```

But I can't figure out how I'm supposed to use the information about the Req to overload the function. How should I proceed?

Comment: Why do you think you need type classes? And I'm guessing that you meant `satisfies :: [Courses] -> Req -> Bool` but I'm not sure

Comment: I'm just learning. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hang on I'll just write it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some typos:

```
data Course = Course { 
   id :: Int, 
   title :: String 
   } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Note the addition of the data constructor name ("Course") and the change from "derives" to "deriving".

```
data Req = Single Course
    | Any [Req]
    | All [Req]
    deriving Show
```

Same here.

```
satisfies :: [Course] -> Req -> Bool
```

Changed the type from [Courses] to [Course].

```
course1 = Course 1 "One"
course2 = Course 2 "Two"
course3 = Course 3 "Three"
course4 = Course 4 "Four"
course5 = Course 5 "Five"

req1 = Single course2
req2 = Any [Single course2, Single course3, Single course5]
req3 = All [Single course1, Single course2]
req4 = Any [req2, req3]
req5 = All [req4, req1]
```

Some Test data.

```
satisfies cs (Single c) = c `elem` cs
```

Match the single course requirement. The other two are beautiful in their simplicity, as most of what they do is already defined in the Prelude, and you can read them like English:

```
satisfies cs (Single c) = c `elem` cs
satisfies cs (Any reqs) = any (satisfies cs) reqs
satisfies cs (All reqs) = all (satisfies cs) reqs
```

Here are the type signatures of your friends `any` and `all`:

```
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

They both take a boolean function and test it for each member of a list. As we have got a list of requirements, and a test function (which it `satisfies` used recursively and partially applied to the courses absolved), we can use them directly.

Let's test:

```
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course1] req1
False
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course2] req1
True
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course1, course2] req1
True
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course1, course2] req1
True
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course1, course2] req3
True
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course1, course3] req3
False
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course1, course3] req2
True
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course4] req2
False
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course4] req5
False
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course5] req2
True
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course4] req4
False
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course2] req4
True
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course2, course3] req4
True
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course5, course3] req4
True
*TestSO15213421> satisfies [course5, course3] req5
False
```

All as expected.

Comment: Haha. I actually ended up coming up with this exact code. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I'm assuming what you want is to take in a `Req` and then depending on it, decide whether a given list of `Courses` satisfy it.

Second I'd make 1 change to make this much less painful,

```
Req = ... Any [Courses] | All [Courses] ...
```

instead of `[Req]`s because really, have requirements that are nested arbitrarily is a bit wonky and weird to deal with for this function.

To do this we're going to do some pattern matching:

```
satisfies :: [Courses] -> Req -> Bool
satisfies courses (Single course) = undefined
satisfies courses (Any reqs)      = undefined
satisfies courses (All reqs)      = undefined
```

Ok so now we've go 3 problems.

First, how do we check if a list contains an element? I'll let you figure out how to do this, let's say you figure out a function `elem` then

```
satisfies courses (Single course) = course `elem` courses
```

Second how do we check if 2 lists intersect at all? Let's say the function is `inter`

```
satisfies courses (Any reqs)      = courses `inter` reqs
```

And finally how do we check if a list contains another? Call it `contains`

```
satisfies courses (All reqs0)      = courses `contains` reqs
```

Now this is a pretty common way to handle ADTs. Breaking them apart and doing a sort of case by case analysis.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice but I actually do need the nesting of the Req = Any [Req] | All [Req] because I want to be able to represent an arbitrarily complex requirement system. I figure between those two (and the Single base case), I should be able to express any dependency I can think of.

Comment: Alright, then it's just a simple matter of instead of just using simple list functions, using slightly more complex ones (you'll have to write them yourself and maybe do some recursion with the Any and All case. It's not a huge deal it just means you can't just drag and drop stuff from Data.List

Comment: @Kyle: Here's some food for thought: how are you going to express the requirement 'at least 3, but no more than 10 courses in the list must have the word "Intermediate" in the title, *unless* there are 7 or more courses where the id is > 500, in which case there must be exactly 4 "Intermediate" courses'?

Comment: @yatima2975: Oh, you're right. I should probably do some sort of Distinct Int [Req]. Thanks!

Comment: @Kyle: You might want something even more general: suppose you add information about the teacher of the course and require 3 classes taught by a professor, and so on, and so on. The idea is instead of fixing a number of criteria (like Single, Any, All), you put a combining function into the Req structure. I should turn this into an answer, but my ideas are still half-formed...

Comment: Oh, gotcha. That way any function could be used. I guess I'm still not thinking functionally. That's good stuff.